# How do I say "Dominate through Darkness" in Latin

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I am looking for the correct phrasing of this for a tattoo design. It is in reference to "dominate through the use of shadows" I have seen Dominentur in Tenebris, as well as Dominari in Tenebris. I'm just curious as to which is the proper phrase for "Dominate through Darkness"

Comment: Welcome to the site! When you get an answer, please wait a few days to see if you get competing ones or if other users see any issues. I assume you want the tattoo design to be good instead of barely sensical, so give it some time.

Comment: Can you also explain what you mean? These words don't have one single meaning and usage in English, so explaining what you want the tattoo to convey is really important.

Comment: Yes, I want the words to convey "to dominate through the use of shadows"

Comment: Dominate doesn't have one single meaning. What do you mean by it? And by shadows you do you literally mean people's shadows? Dark places in general? Shades of the underworld? What does it mean to "dominate through the use of shadows"? Using shadows as a means to control what, the world? To excel in life? The more specific you are, the better others can give you a more accurate response.

Comment: *Dominentur in tenebris* can mean "let them dominate in the dark", and *dominari in tenebris* can mean "to dominate in the dark". But note that the bare infinitive *dominari* does not mean "in order to dominate", but simply "to dominate" (as in "to dominate is one way to think about governing"). In English "to" can imply "in order to", but that won't usually work in Latin. If you want the "in order to" sense, you'll need to say it some other way.